Problem with generics and interfaces and the inability to cast the concrete type to the interface
I have the following scenario
public interface IEvent {}
public interface IEventHandler<T> where T : IEvent {
   void Handle(T evt);
}

public class ItemCreatedEvent : IEvent {}
public class ItemCreatedEventHandler : IEventHandler<ItemCreatedEvent> {
   void Handle(ItemCreatedEvent evt) { ... }
}

All of the following is fine:

I can get the concrete type of the event (ie. I can get an object of type ItemCreatedEvent)
Based on that, I can determine the concrete type of the handler (ie. ItemCreatedEventHandler)
I can make an instance of this type (Activator.CreateInstance(handlerType))

The problem now arrives when I want to call the .Handle() method on this instance
...

var handler = (IEventHandler)Activator.CreateInstance(handlerType);
handler?.Handle(evt);

This provides me with the following issues:

If I cast to (IEventHandler), the Handle() method is unknown
If I cast to (IEventHandler<IEvent>), it fails because "Cannot implicitly convert from ItemCreatedEventHandler to IEventHandler<IEvent>"

From what I've found so far, this has to do with type invariance, but I'm not finding anything to help me solve the issue.
Thanks!

Does a non-generic IEventHandler exist? You haven't shared it's definition in your example.

if you require reflection access to such APIs, it is common for the non-generic base (which seems to be IEventHandler in this case) to support the same API in a non-generic way; by which I mean: is it possible for IEventHandler (the non-generic version) to add a Handle(IEvent evt) method, that you can use in this case, with the specific implementation dealing with the cast?

Out of interest, what does the Method in whcih you want to call the Activator/what are the parameters it will be getting?

My thinking is that if you start out by having a object of the event, from which you get the event type which you then use to determine which handlertype to use, you could just use that object as a cast helper.


If I cast to (IEventHandler<IEvent>), it fails because "Cannot implicitly convert from ItemCreatedEventHandler to IEventHandler<IEvent>"

That's because for IEventHandler<T>, T is invariant, so a IEventHandler<ItemCreatedEvent> is not a IEventHandler<IEvent>.
In your example, it's not possible to make that T covariant, because T is used in an input position within the interface definition, and therefore it would not be type-safe to do so:
void Handle(T evt);

Once you start with reflection here, you'll need to continue with reflection:
var handler = Activator.CreateInstance(handlerType);
var method = handler.GetMethod("Handle");
method.Invoke(handler, new object[] { evt });


You can define a non-generic interface IEventHandler, and implement the non-generic method in the generic interface like this:
public interface IEventHandler {
    void Handle(IEvent evt);
}
public interface IEventHandler<T> : IEventHandler where T : IEvent {
    void IEventHandler.Handle(IEvent evt) => Handle((T)evt);
    void Handle(T evt);
}


With the caveat that this isn't type safe.

Ok so there have already been some pretty great answers, but I still found this an interesting problem, so I thought Id just share my solution.
For this one I had to rely on some assumtions, since you didnt give us the information of exactly HOW you get the EventType/Object.
So I assumed you had some HandleEvent Method that you give the  object, it then determines the Handletype and trys to do the activator.
What I have done is added some more generics to that Method.
    public void StartingPoint()
    {
        ItemCreatedEvent evt = new();
        HandleEvent(evt);
    }

    public void HandleEvent<TEvent>(TEvent evt) where TEvent: IEvent
    {
        //I just assume you did something like this to get the type
        Type? typ = GetHandleType<TEvent>();

        if (typ is null)
        {
            return;
        }

        var handler = (IEventHandler<TEvent>) Activator.CreateInstance(typ);
        handler?.Handle(evt);
    }

    //Also here is my GetHandleType method if you are interested
    private Type? GetHandleType<TEvent>() where TEvent : IEvent
    {
        Type? typ = null;
        Type eventType = typeof(TEvent);

        string eventTypeName = eventType.Name;
        string handlerNameGuess = eventTypeName + "Handler"; //I assumed youd keep with the naming convention.

        Type[] allMyTypes = eventType.Assembly.GetTypes();

        Type? foundHandler = allMyTypes.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Name == handlerNameGuess, null);

        var checkType = typeof(IEventHandler<TEvent>);

        if (foundHandler?.GetInterfaces().Contains(checkType) ?? false)
        {
            typ = foundHandler;
        }

        return typ;
    }

